# How to access the nested JSON params from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code in controller:

```
def login
  @user = params[:user]
  render :json => @user
end
```

And here is my POST data:

```
{
  "user": {
    "email":"2",
    "password":2
  }
}
```

But I can only retrieve a JSON like:

```
{
  "email": "2",
  "password": 2
}
```

How can I parse JSON by params for both email and password, and use the parameter like

```
params[:email]
params[:password]
```

so that i can compare my params to the database.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to what I understood, you need to get the data `email` and `password` directly from `params[]`. This is simply a nested params so you can do

```
params['user']['email']
params['user']['password']
```